# onChange Not Working in react-select Dropdown within a react-bootstrap Modal and react-draggable Component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-select, react-functional-component

I'm using the react-select library in a React project to render a dropdown select box. I have defined an options array that contains a single option with the label "a". I have also defined an onChange function that should log the selected option to the console when an option is selected.

Additionally, I'm using the react-bootstrap library's Modal component to create a popup, and the react-draggable library's Draggable component to make the popup draggable.

Here's my code:

```
import React from "react";
import Select from "react-select";
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Modal'
import Draggable from 'react-draggable'

function App() {
  const onChange = (selectedOption) => {
    console.log("Selected Option:", selectedOption);
  };

  const options = [
    {
      label: "a",
    },
  ];

  const style={
    width:"100px",
    height:"100px",
    backgroundColor:"green"
  };  

  return (
    <div>
      <Draggable>
        <Modal show={true}>
          <Modal.Body>
            <div style={style}>Comp</div>
          </Modal.Body>
        </Modal>
      </Draggable>
      <div style={style}>
        Comp2
      </div>
      <Select options={options} onChange={(option) => onChange(option)} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Despite everything appearing to be set up correctly, when I open the dropdown and select the "a" option, the onChange function is not being called.

Can anyone help me figure out why the onChange function is not being called when an option is selected?

Comment: Select seems to be a component, since written with capital 'S'. What happens inside that component does it use the onChange property you send to it?

Comment: [Your code works](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tkfzxv?file=src%2FApp.js)

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I am actually looking for a way to make the modal window appear and also be able to use the Select component.

Answer (score 0):

In the `options` object, each element must contain a `value` property.

```
const options = [
    {
        value: "a",
        label: "a",
    },
];
```

Comment: This is an example I created to post a code snippet here. The problem is not related to the "options" array but to the fact that the "onChange" function is not being called.

Comment: Try setting the initial `value` to something, so the option actually changes the selected value.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is working fine, but you need to set your modal show={false} initially.

```
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
import { Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Draggable from 'react-draggable';

export default function App(props) {
  const onChange = selectedOption => {
    console.log('Selected Option:', selectedOption);
  };

  const options = [
    {
      label: 'a',
    },
  ];

  const style = {
    width: '100px',
    height: '100px',
    backgroundColor: 'green',
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Draggable>
        <Modal show={false}>
          <Modal.Body>
            <div style={style}>Comp</div>
          </Modal.Body>
        </Modal>
      </Draggable>
      <div style={style}>
        Comp2
      </div>

      <Select options={options} onChange={option => onChange(option)} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I am actually looking for a way to make the modal window appear and also be able to use the Select component.

Comment: When a modal is open Unfortunately, there's no event. you need to check other solutions rather than a modal.